# PyCharm Python Output collapses for large datasets

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pycharm, dataset

I have a `csv` file with only 11 columns and a few thousand rows.

When I use `Pandas` to show the content in console, I get `...` after the first couple of rows.

[image]

How do I disable this behavior, so everything is printed out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following options in pandas:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)    
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
```

In this way, the entire df will be printed.

Obviously, you can also set a pre-defined number of columns/rows.

```
max_rows = 100
max_cols = 100
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', max_cols )    
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', max_rows)
```